# Android 13: move my foreground notification back up?

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app which has a foreground task, and posts an ongoing notification.

Earlier until version 12, it was displayed at the topmost place on the notification drawer.

Android 13 changes this, making it appear down below:

[image]

As you can see, messenger is preceding my application.

Can I somehow post the ongoing notification to appear at the top?

I'm using it a lot so would be much more comfortable if I can have it on top (where now the messenger is).

Notification is created with basic builder:

```
Notification.Builder b;
Notification notification = b.setTicker(ticker)
        .setSmallIcon(smallicon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();
```

Can I somehow force it to the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set priority height in your code. And also avoid setting messenger app superposition on other apps. I think it will help.

Comment: I only have messenger lite, so it's not superpositioning any other apps. For the record, how can I set the priority, and which priority would be sufficient?

Comment: Add this line it may help `.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);`